# Rspec models not from codebase

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

I'm wondering if anyone could shed some light on the best way to test code that works with database models, but does not care what that model is.

Our app has a kind of synchronisation engine that keeps data on a remote server in sync with data on our system, and operates on a number of database models. It is also designed to work with multiple remote systems, and as such contains a number of internal data models which later get mapped to our actual database records.

As an example, we have something like this:

```
class RemoteResource < Syncable
  maps_to ::InternalDbModel
  ....
end
```

Here, the sync engine would pull data from any of the remote servers and convert it into a `RemoteResource` instance, and later this would get translated into an `InternalDbModel` for persistence.

Due to the generic design, the sync engine doesn't care what database models it is converting to. So long as they meet certain criteria, they are valid.

My question revolves around testing this sort of code. Due to time constraints, I've had to write tests that I simply don't like - the tests involve creating records of actual models used by the app, but I don't like this for a number of reasons:

- Each test has to know about the model in order to create the records
- If the model has other requirements, they must be fulfilled first, which is completely irrelevant for the test itself
- It is not the model that I want to test
- It makes the tests brittle to any changes in those models

The syncable class is fine, as I am able to simply stub a class in the test and that works fine. But how can I do something similar for the active record model? Is there a way that I can create a kind of anonymous model class for these kind of tests? I will need to be able to persist the data as some of the sync engine process tests will require that data already exists, but i want this data to be completely independent of the main app itself.

I hope this makes sense

### Example

**Sync engine resource**

```
class Integration::Resources::Account < Syncable
  maps_to ::Account

  string :name
  string :description
  belongs_to :company, Integration::Resources::Company, required: true
  belongs_to :currency, Integration::Resources::Currency, required: true
end
```

**Part being tested**

I want to test a bit of code that checks that the required `belongs_to` relations of the `Account` resource as present. If they're not, it simply ignores the resources, but otherwise it continues.

Part of this involves loading the database records that are associated with the resources. So if the `currency` association has been set to an instance of the `Integration::Resources::Account` class, then the engine will retrieve that record from the database. If that record is not found, then the association is considered missing and thus the resource is ignored as it is required.

In this scenario, I currently have to:

- Create a currency record
- Create a company record
- Instantiate a currency resource
- Instantiate a company resource
- THEN instantiate the account resource with the other resources, and run the test

To me, there is far too much knowledge here about the Account resource, as this is not what I am testing. I simply want to test the code that is ignoring resources with a missing association.

What I want to do is
- Create a dummy model class
  - Only a single association
- Create a dummy resource class (this is ok)
  - Only a single association
- Test

This way the test only knows what it needs to know. Any changes to any other code would then not break this test which stops it being so brittle.

Comment: i find this a rather abstract problem description. it's basically opinion based. could you give a concrete example of the code that is bothering you? that could spark an idea of how to solve your "problem".

Comment: [This gem](https://github.com/jpignata/temping) allows you to create temporary database tables for use in tests. Might be useful for your use case. (It does tend to slow tests down a bit though because the tables have to be created from scratch at the start of the test suite)

Comment: @phoet I've added an example, hopefully that clears things up a bit. I realise it is a little subjective, but it just feels like a big no-no in terms of testing

Comment: @Slicedpan thanks for that, I'll take a look. Does seem close to what I want :)